# Find whether several array's elements have the same coordinates

Tags: arrays, macos, swift2, equality

I'm writing a Swift `extension` that checks if two or more CGPoints in array have the same coordinates. Having this code I can check all points in array.
**But how to check just several elements (not all)?**

Here's the extension...

```
import Foundation

extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    func equalCoordinates() -> Bool {

        if let firstElement = first {

            return dropFirst().contains { $0 == firstElement }

        }

        return true
    }
}
```

If two (or more) red CGPoints have identical coordinates they must be turned into green ones.

...and a code in ViewController using `equalCoordinates()` method:

```
func drawn() {

    let colorArray = array.map { $0.pointCoord()[0] }

    for dot in array {

        for cPoint in dot.pointCoord() {

            if colorArray.equalCoordinates() {

                let altColor = dot.alternativePointColour()
                draw(cPoint, color: altColor)

            } else {

                let color = dot.pointColour()
                draw(cPoint, color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}

...........

Swift.print(colorArray.equalCoordinates())

...........
```

Comment: What do you mean by several? A range of them? A set of indices of them? One at a time?

Comment: @ColGraff Two or more CGPoints in a range. With indices if it's possible.

Comment: So you also want to return the indices of the equal elements?

Comment: @ColGraff Yes I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With absolutely no concern given to efficiency (that can be improved depending on the size of your data), this is how I'd probably go about it. Each piece is pretty simple, so you should be able to adapt it to a wide variety of different outputs (if you prefer something other than `IndexSet` for instance).

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

// We could put this on Collection rather than Array, but then we'd have to rewrite
// IndexSet on generic indices or use [Index].
extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    func uniqueElements() -> [Element] {
        // This is O(n^2), but it's hard to beat that without adding either 
        // Hashable (for Set) or Comparable (to pre-sort) to the requirements,
        // neither of which CGPoints have by default.
        var uniqueElements: [Element] = []

        for element in self {
            if !uniqueElements.contains(element) {
                uniqueElements.append(element)
            }
        }
        return uniqueElements
    }

    func indexSet(of element: Element) -> IndexSet {
        var indices = IndexSet()
        for (index, member) in enumerated() {
            if element == member {
                indices.insert(index)
            }
        }
        return indices
    }

    func indexSetsGroupedByEquality() -> [(element: Element, indexSet: IndexSet)] {
        return uniqueElements().map { element in (element, indexSet(of: element)) }
    }

    func indexSetsOfCollidingElements() -> [IndexSet] {
        func hasCollisions(_: Element, indexSet: IndexSet) -> Bool { return indexSet.count > 1 }

        return indexSetsGroupedByEquality()
            .filter(hasCollisions)
            .map { $0.indexSet }
    }
}

let points  = [
    CGPoint(x:1,y:1),
    CGPoint(x:2,y:1),
    CGPoint(x:1,y:1),
    CGPoint(x:3,y:1),
    CGPoint(x:2,y:1),
]

print(points.indexSetsOfCollidingElements().map(Array.init))

// [[0, 2], [1, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, Rob. But I've got an error. I typed `colorArray.indexSetsOfCollidingElements().map(Array.init)` and got a message in Xcode: `Ambiguous reference to member "init"`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: That map is just get to from an IndexSet into an Array so I could print it more easily. You don't generally need that. If you want an array of indices rather than an index set, just rewrite the code to generate arrays in the first place. If you're unclear how to rewrite it, this is IMO a good piece of code to study. You should be able to work out exactly what it's doing. Nothing here is intended to be tricky. (If you still have trouble, ask about the method you're having trouble with, and I'll add more comments in the answer.)

Comment: Xcode says: `Type '[NSIndexSet]' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'`.

Comment: That method returns an array of [IndexSet] they indicates where the conflicts. You need to check its count. Arrays are not Booleans. if takes a Boolean. But you said you needed index paths too.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2 version

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {    
    func uniqueElements() -> [Element] {
        var uniqueElements: [Element] = []
    
        for element in self {
            if !uniqueElements.contains(element) {
                uniqueElements.append(element)
            }
        }
        return uniqueElements
    }
    func indexSet(of element: Element) -> NSIndexSet { 
        let indices = NSIndexSet()
    
        for (index, member) in enumerate() {           
            if element == member {
                indices.insertValue(index, inPropertyWithKey: "")
            }
        }
        return indices
    }
    func indexSetsGroupedByEquality() -> [(element: Element, 
                                          indexSet: NSIndexSet)] {
        return uniqueElements().map { element in 
            (element, indexSet(of: element))
        }
    }
    func indexSetsOfCollidingElements() -> [NSIndexSet] {
        func hasCollisions(_: Element, indexSet: NSIndexSet) -> Bool {
            return indexSet.count > 0
        }
        return indexSetsGroupedByEquality().filter(hasCollisions)
                                            .map { $0.indexSet }
    }
}
```